# Elements within a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a below mentioned list:

```
a= ['1234,5678\n','90123,45678\n']
```

The expected output I'm working towards is this:

```
op = [['1234','5678'],['90123','45678']]
```

Basically a list of lists with individual elements referring to a particular column.

Using the below mentioned code i get the following output:

```
a = ['1234,5678\n','90123,45678\n']

new_list = []

for element in a:
    #remove new lines
    new_list.append(element.splitlines())
    
print(new_list)

output:[['1234,5678'], ['90123,45678']]
```

Any direction regarding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Like this? `op = [x.strip().split(",") for x in a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
a= ['1234,5678\n','90123,45678\n']
a = ['1234,5678\n','90123,45678\n']

new_list = []

for element in a:
    #remove new lines
    new_list.append(element.strip("\n").split(","))
    
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [i.strip("\n").split(",") for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the strings in your input list appears to follow the CSV format, you can use `csv.reader` to parse them:

```
import csv
list(csv.reader(a))
```

This returns:

```
[['1234', '5678'], ['90123', '45678']]
```